# KVM Virtual windows7 Paused on starting in Centos

Tags: windows-7, kvm-virtualization

I'm running CentOs 6 and just installed Windows7 in KVM Virtual Machine Manager, But when starting the win7 virtual machine then goes to pause mode , the following content of our win7 xml file :

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>cqg.vm.bd</name>
  <uuid>4edf3189-bebe-fd07-1374-581221186b99</uuid>
  <memory>3072000</memory>
  <currentMemory>3072000</currentMemory>
  <vcpu>4</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='rhel6.2.0'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='localtime'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='threads'/>
      <source file='/gt/fsrvthis/virtual-servers-active/cqg.vm.bd/cqg.vm.bd-os.disk'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='virtio'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:f5:ff:01'/>
      <source bridge='bridge1'/>
      <model type='virtio' />
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes'/>
    <video>
      <model type='vga' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Comment: Check the log files.

Comment: chkconfig --del libvirt-guests;chkconfig --add libvirt-guests;chkconfig libvirt-guests off

Answer (score 1):

```
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='threads'/>
  <source file='/gt/fsrvthis/virtual-servers-active/cqg.vm.bd/cqg.vm.bd-os.disk'/>
  <target dev='hda' bus='virtio'/>
</disk>
```

This should be `target dev='vda' bus='virtio'`

Check the libvirt logs, VMs are set to go into pause on EIO or ENOSPACE, so if the VM is hitting an IO issue with reading or writing to the local disks, it will pause. If it runs out of space, it will also pause.